# Why can't I have the same name in two way binding directive components in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, directive, angular-components

I have a directive component that has two way binding in a property.
But when the attribute has the same name as the property it seems like it is always undefined. But when I change to something else it does what I expected.

The component is used like so:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="relatedContentsRandom">
          <related-content related-content="relatedContentsRandom" content-id="selectedVideoId"
            in-watch-later="inWatchLater" autoplay="autoplay" is-watch-list="isWatchList" />
</div>
```

The property in question is autoplay, which has this structure in the controller that is passing it into the component.

```js
$scope.autoplay = {
      selected: false,
      count: 0,
    };
```

And part of the component:

```js
scope: {
        relatedContent: "<",
        contentId: "<",
        inWatchLater: "<",
        autoplay: "=autoplay", // or autoplay: "="
        isWatchList: "<"
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        _init();

        function _init() {
          console.log(scope.autoplay);
          console.log(scope.relatedContent);
        }
...
```

If I change the property in the component to use a different name, like `autoplay: "=atp"` and then in the component use just change the attribute name, then it shows me the correct value.

Why does this simple change work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the external and internal name of the scope property to be the same, just use `=` with no name afterward.

```js
scope: {
    ...
    autoplay: "=",
    ...
}
```

Here's the relevant AngularJS documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

Comment: Yeah I know that. You can see it in the other props. That wasn't the question.

Comment: Is your goal to have both the internal scope property and the public attribute be named ‘autoplay’?

Comment: Yes. I don't mind having another name for the internal one, but I just wanted to know why, in this case, it's not working like I expected it to when it has the same name in the internal scope and public attribute.

Comment: Then `autoplay: "="` is in fact the solution. While it's an interesting question why it doesn't work when you manually specify the same name, it's neither here nor there. AngularJS provides an official solution, so use it.

Comment: I've edited the question, because when I also use just the `=` it also remains undefined.

Comment: I see. Well I'm just shooting in the dark now, but have you tried using the built-in `$onInit` lifecycle hook instead your custom `_init` implementation? There might be something weird with the parent scope property having the same name which `$onInit` knows how to handle. [Here are the docs for it](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: In my case I don't think I have any use for `$onInit` because I don't do anything in my `_init` with the autoplay variable. I use it in the template and when everything is rendered it still shows as undefined, unless I change the attribute name to something else.
Also, I'm using a directive as a component, did you mean use `$onInit` in the `controller` property?

Comment: I did, but I see now that it wouldn't do any good. You're just using it to debug. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. It must have something to do with parent scope inheritance, I'm just not sure what it would be. If I think of anything else, I'll come back and update this.